# Angular route resolve not passing to controller

Tags: angularjs

For some reason whatever i do i cannot get my data to the controller no matter what i do, i keep getting this error

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: initDataProvider <- initData <- PackingScanController

first file

```
var Application = angular.module('ReporterApplication', ['ngRoute']);


Application.config(['$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider',

    function($routeProvider, $interpolateProvider) {

        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');

        $routeProvider

            .when('/packing/scan.html', {
                controller: 'PackingScanController',
                templateUrl: 'packing/scan.html',
                resolve: {

                    initData : function () {
                        return "shite";
                    }


                }
            }) etc more code
```

second file

```
Application.controller('PackingScanController', ['$scope', '$http', 'initData', function($scope, $http, initData) {

    var packer = this;

    $scope.packedToday = initData;
```

Comment: The posted code is fine. I assume that you code is different from what you posted here.

Comment: initData seems to not be injected as an angular module, where do you define it and how ?

Comment: There night be problem with HTML, can you post HTML code and how you bind controllers?

Comment: Just a doubt, not sure. Should the `initData` be preceded with `$`?

Comment: @ShijuKBabu No, you can name services whatever you want (valid identifier).

Comment: I know. But the first one in quotes I meant. Second can be alias. May be I'm wrong

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice the resolve in route provider

Comment: @ShijuKBabu Then there will be another error, because there is no `$initData` service available, unless you resolve route with `$initData: function() {...}`.

Comment: Yup, Just noticed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code is all right, you are injecting `initData` properly with resolve route block. However you are probably using explicit `ngController` in you route template. You don't want it, and of course in this case there is no `initData` service available which results in error you are getting.

Solution is simple: just remove

```
ng-controller="PackingScanController"
```

from your `packing/scan.html` template and it will work fine.

Explicit controller binding is not needed in this case since template is already bound properly to controller instance created behind the scene by `$route` service, with all necessary dependencies properly injected.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Controller in config is defined for entire template.